# akka path match on last optional element

Tags: scala, akka-http

The last path element is optional so I created this matcher

```
pathPrefix("the-endpoint" / Segment / Segment.?) { (left[String], right: Option[String]) => ... }
```

Problem is that this path is only invoked if I add the trailing "/" slash character:

i.e. don't add the last path part:

```
curl localhost:12345/the-endpoint/firstsegment
The requested resource could not be found
```

but

```
curl localhost:12345/the-endpoint/firstsegment/
... all good , gets to the path as expected ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [ignoreTrailingSlash](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/ignoreTrailingSlash.html) directive:

```
ignoreTrailingSlash {
  path("the-endpoint" / Segment / Segment.?) { (left: String, right: Option[String]) =>
    // ...
  }
}
```